# 2-group heterogeneity index

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

I have a dataset with two distinct groups (A and B) belonging to 3 different categories (1, 2, 3):

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(100)
df <- tibble(Group = sample(c(1, 2, 3), 20, replace = T),Company = sample(c('A', 'B'), 20, replace = T))
```

I want to come come up with a metric that characterizes group composition across the timespan.

Thus far, I have used an index based on Shannon's Index which gives a measure of heterogeneity varying between 0 and 1. With 1 being a perfectly heterogeneous (equal representation of each group) and 0 being completely homogeneous (only 1 group is represented):

```
df %>% 
   group_by(Group, Company) %>% 
   summarise(n=n()) %>% 
   mutate(p = n / sum(n)) %>% 
   mutate(Shannon = -(p*log2(p) + (1-p)))
```

Yielding:

```
   Group    Company n          p    Shannon
   <dbl>    <chr>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
    1         A     2   0.6666667   0.05664167
    1         B     1   0.3333333   -0.13834583
    2         A     4   0.5000000   0.00000000
    2         B     4   0.5000000   0.00000000
    3         A     1   0.1111111   -0.53667500
    3         B     8   0.8888889   0.03993333
```

However, I am looking for an index between [-1, +1]. Where the index yields -1 when only group A is present at a time point, +1 when only group B is present at a time point, 0 being an equal representation.

How can I create such an index? I have looked at measures such as Moran's I as inspiration, but they do not seem to suit the need.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution might be to calculate the mean.
I transformed `Company` into `value` with A = -1 and B = 1 and calculated the mean by Group.
The result will be an index for each Group, with -1 when `Company` has just "A"s or 1 when there are just "B"s.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 
                               2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3), Company = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
                                                                    "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", 
                                                                    "A", "B")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                   "data.frame"))
```

**Code**

```
df %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(Company == "A", -1, 1)) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(index = mean(value))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Group  index
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1  0.333
2     2 -0.429
3     3  0.429
```